# Allowing access for specific users in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security to Secure my Web App.
I have a page where I show `foo` objects for administrators.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/show_foo/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

But now I have a requirement that a `foo` cannot be seen by all the Administrators, for example only administrators with city="New York" can access to the element.

I've did something in my controller to solve this :

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/show_foo"
public ModelAndView showfunction(Principal user)
{
User user2 = userService.getUserByName(user.getName());
if(/* some checks on user2 */)
   /* show page */
else
  /* show error page*/
}
```

So my question is : can I avoid the database call, because I need this almost in all of my pages and I find it ugly to check each time at the top of any controller the same thing over and over. Is there a Spring Security feature for this kind of use cases?.

Comment: I don't think there is. Probably, you can implement `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` on successful authentication, fetch the city and keep it in the session. For the subsequent requests, you can get the value from session instead of querying database

Comment: Yes I already have an AuthneticationSuccessHandler. I've taught  about it, but I still have to check inside my controller, can this be avoided somehow too ?

Comment: Okay. Not aware if any other solution is available. Probably add a filter before all the controllers.

Answer (score 3):

With Expression based rules you can accesss principal even on rule. See: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

For example if you can include needed information on principal object.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/show_foo/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and principal.name=='xyzzy' " />
```

Comment: I cannot access my user attributes from here ... I think.

Comment: You can modify your UserDetails class to contain necessary information.  Many of the authentication providers will create a UserDetails object as the principal.

Comment: Yes but I assume that *xyzzy* is static in this case, which is not good for me. I need something like *principal.name=foo.creator.name* , which is not possible.

Comment: You could wire there your own `PermissionEvaluator` See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-permission-evaluator for that. Could be simpler than full blown ACL

Answer (score 1):

you have to put in some logic.

1.) Either load the user and country mapping and store somewhere in `Static` `HashMap`, remember to update the map if any changes done in mapping, can store same at session level.

2.) Load entries in `2nd level cache,` or make queries cacheable, enable `query caching` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate Spring Security with Domain-ACLs. See a full explanation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls).

Yo can consider mapping the relationship between Administrators and Cities using 
`ACL_OBJECT_IDENTITY` instances.